# How to accept a bug fix into local code base

Tags: git

I'm new to git and am trying to make the bitcoin client, bitcoind. It looks like there is a build issue in osx high sierra, https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/12009. Anyway the bug fix is being put into v0.15.2 but it's not out yet and so I'm using v0.15.1. How can I pull down and merge the bug fix into my local code?

Comment: Do you create new branch from master/develop for bug fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `origin` is https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin do

```
git pull origin pull/12032/head
```

This fetches branch `pull/12032/head` (pull requests at GitHub are branches with these special names) and merges it (`git pull` is really `git fetch` + `git merge`) into the current branch.